# c# how to add and remove a Point to a Queue

Tags: c#, queue, point

can you tell me how I can add and remove a Point to a Queue.
Because Dequeue returns an implicit error.
f.e.

```
Queue Q = new Queue();
Point I = new Point(0,0);
Point J = new Point(0,0);
Q.Enqueue(J);
J = Q.Dequeue();
```

Comment: Oh Sorry my fault, you can Ignore `while (Q != null)`. I simply want to know, how to add a `Point` to a `Queue` and Dequeue it in another `Point`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Queue.Dequeue` returns an object, which you need to cast to the correct type:

```
Queue Q = new Queue();
Point J = new Point(0, 0);
Q.Enqueue(J);
while (Q != null)  //Loop is a problem--see below
{
    J = (Point)Q.Dequeue();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the generic version of `Queue`, `Queue<T>`. Since your queue is then of the type you declare, `Dequeue` returns objects of that type, so there's no need for a cast:

```
Point J2 = new Point(0, 0);
Queue<Point> Q2 = new Queue<Point>();
Q2.Enqueue(J2);
J2 = Q2.Dequeue();
```

Finally, your `while` loop will throw an `InvalidOperationException` when it does execute, because after the first dequeue, you attempt to dequeue again when the queue is now empty.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to use the generic verion of Queue like so:

```
var Q = new Queue<Point>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the code. I had failed to properly indicate the start of the code block and then '<Point>' was filtered out because it looked like a tag.